# soup server example of gjs at github - server stops listening after 2 seconds

Tags: gjs

I was playing around with a soup server example of https://github.com/GNOME/gjs/blob/master/examples/http-server.js
using cjs, but wasnt able to connect to the server with the browser.
Then i checked the open connections with `ss -tunl` directly after starting the server and saw that, the server opens on localhost port 1080, but after doing a loop of checks with ss, i saw that it disappears, after two seconds, altough cjs is still executing the Main loop.

It took me 2 hours to get it work, but i cant explain, why it now works.

i changed the orginal main function of the example:

```
function main() {
    let server = new Soup.Server();
    server.add_handler('/', handler);
    server.add_handler('/hello', helloHandler);
    server.listen_local(1080, Soup.ServerListenOptions.IPV4_ONLY);
}
```

by setting the local server variable to a global variable

```
var server;
function main() {
    server = new Soup.Server();
    server.add_handler('/', handler);
    server.add_handler('/hello', helloHandler);
    server.listen_local(1080, Soup.ServerListenOptions.IPV4_ONLY);
}
```

that keeps the server open, but if i change it back to the orginal function, it will again close after two seconds.

Does anybody have some idea? Is this a problem of GLIB MainLoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/issues/569) open about this that puzzled me, but now that I see your workaround I understand why it is happening. Thank you!

After `main()` finishes, the `server` variable is no longer reachable by any JS code, so it is deleted in the next garbage collection, which apparently happens after about 2 seconds.

Lifting `server` out of `main()` means it is in scope and therefore reachable during the entire execution of the program, so it is not deleted until the end of the program.

Alternative ways to fix the problem would be to add it as a property on another object that remains in scope (e.g., `loop.server = new Soup.Server()` or use a `Gio.Application` subclass and set `this.server = new Soup.Server()` in its `activate` method.

The example code should be fixed to do one of these things.

Comment: hi, im a big fan of GJS - great job. Your response of garbage collection showing me, that i have a fundamental misunderstanding, how gjs works. I thought each C library created GObject Object has its own Object representation in gjs and dereferencing the object in GJS means only that the garbage collector elimantes the object in the JAVASCRIPT area, but i also have to explictly kill the object over C library methods to free it complete from memory. But here the server got killed, so gjs manages also the killing over C library methods?Can you explain the second question above, please?

Comment: i have edited my question and added a new question, because of your answer

Comment: Please don't edit your question into another question - nobody will see it and it won't be searchable. Just open a new question, that way more people might be able to help you.

Comment: removed the edit